cloud dataflow environment variable for python file for flex template launch in docker file
In case of single pipeline setting python file as environment variable in docker file will be feasible.What if I want to deploy multiple pipelines
So for multiple pipelines I tried with empty string in docker file and during launch of job I passed python file path like how it is inside docker container and I see the below error
Error occurred in the launcher container: py_file is required
